# Feather Icons inside Javascript append not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons

I'm using Feather icons successfully inside a `<textarea>` like so:

```
<i data-feather="message-circle" class="fea icon-sm icons"></i> 
<textarea style="resize:none" required=""></textarea>
```

However, when I try to duplicate the row with a Javascript function, the icons do not show up.

```
$(wrapper).append('<i data-feather="message-circle" class="fea icon-sm icons"></i> 
<textarea style="resize:none" required=""></textarea>');
```

where `wrapper` is a div container

```
var wrapper = $(".container1");
```

EDIT: Full function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 60;
    //var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var wrapper = ".container1";
    var add_button      = $(".add_question_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-12"> <div class="form-group position-relative"> <label>Screening Question</label> <i data-feather="email" class="fea icon-sm icons"></i> <textarea style="resize:none" id="question" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Your Question" rows="5" class="form-control pl-5" required=""></textarea> </div> </div><!--end col--> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="form-group position-relative"> <label>Answer</label> <i data-feather="email" class="fea icon-sm icons"></i> <textarea style="resize:none" id="answer" type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Answer" rows="5" class="form-control pl-5" required=""></textarea> </div> </div><!--end col--> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="form-group position-relative"> <label>Keywords</label> <i data-feather="email" class="fea icon-sm icons"></i> <textarea style="resize:none" id="buzzwords" type="text" name="buzzwords" placeholder="Comma Separated Buzzwords and Phrases" rows="5" class="form-control pl-5" required=""></textarea> </div> </div>'); //add input box
            feather.replace()
        }
        else
        {
            alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you make sure feather initiation script is at the end of body tag and after the custom script you're applying?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
  <body>

    <script>
      //your custom js here
      feather.replace()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit:

After looking at the full function edited in question, looks like problem is in the icon name 'email', change it to '**mail**':

```
<i data-feather="email" class="fea icon-sm icons"></i>
```

jsfiddle playground:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ebfvydg/1/

Comment: yes, that seems to be my setup. Wish that was the case.

Comment: ah here we go: replace.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toSvg' of undefined

Comment: this was occurring before when I had a bad icon name. This one has been used successfully, so not sure of the issue here.

Comment: Tried this: `var wrapper = ".container1";` ?

Comment: that wasn't it. I edited my original post with the full function

Comment: Look at the edit in my answer, problem is in icon name!

Comment: thank you for putting up with my carelessness! Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked, I added the jsfiddle I used to play around until issue was found.

Answer (score 0):

Load the data-feather script and put feather.replace(); inside the javascript function. Also change data-feather="email" to data-feather="mail" and it will work.